# Page Tab Not Showing Up on Pages

Tags: tabs, facebook-apps

I have created a page tab (which I have done before without any trouble) but am now not seeing it on either of our two fan pages.  I keep seeing a reference to "add to page" but can't seem to find this option.  When I go to the fan page and edit it, click on apps, the new page tab I created is not there.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be changing things a lot lately. You should check out the [Facebook Page Tab Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) if you haven't already; Assuming you haven't answered your question in the past 30 days.